# Spark sort RDD and join their rank

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an `RDD[(VertexId, Double)]`, and I want to sort it by `_._2` and join the index(rank) with this RDD. Therefore I can get an element and its rank by `filter`.

Currently I sort the RDD by `sortBy`, but I do not know how to join a RDD with its rank. So I collect it as a sequence and zip it with its index. But this is not efficient. I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to do that.

The code I'm using right now are:

```
val tmpRes = graph.vertices.sortBy(_._2, ascending = false) // Sort all nodes by its PR score in descending order
      .collect() // collect to master, this may be very expensive

    tmpRes.zip(tmpRes.indices) // zip with index
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if, by any chance, you'd like to bring back to the driver only **n** first tuples, then maybe you could use **takeOrdered(n, [ordering])** where **n** is the number of results to bring back and **ordering** the comparator you'd like to use.

Otherwise, you can use the **zipWithIndex** transformation that will transform you `RDD[(VertexId, Double)]` into a `RDD[((VertexId, Double), Long)]` with the proper index (of course you should do that after your sort).

For example :

```
scala> val data = sc.parallelize(List(("A", 1), ("B", 2)))
scala> val sorted = data.sortBy(_._2)
scala> sorted.zipWithIndex.collect()
res1: Array[((String, Int), Long)] = Array(((A,1),0), ((B,2),1))
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks ssaboum. I thought `zipWithIndex` will zip the index_in_partition + partition_offset. But after sorting the index becomes the ranking instead of the old index. BTW I'm using `top` for taking first n ordered elements in an RDD. Seems it works similar to `takeOrdered`.